# Does SMIME 4, or any prior version, support multiple private keys for a single individual?

Tags: smime

I am investigating S/MIME and if it's possible to have a device-specific signing key (or if that's a good idea).

The intention is to reduce risk by making the private key read only on the device(es) it was requested from.  This would prevent the need to expose the cleartext private key, export, import, and securely erase whatever medium was used to transport that private data.

Does a solution like this exist, or is this a less-than-ideal request?

What might be better?

Comment: So, when I want to encrypt an email for you, I fetch all public keys belonging to you and encrypt one copy of the message to each key -- sorta like having multiple recipients in the To: list, each with the same email address but different public keys. I doubt there's anything in S/MIME itself that would prevent this, but I think the bigger issue will be the surrounding infrastructure, ie when I send you an encrypted email using Outlook, Thunderbird, some-random-Android-email-app, will those programs know to do this? Or will you end up receiving msgs that only decrypt on one of your devices?

Comment: ... If I reply from my phone's gmail app, will that look to my computer's Outlook like it came from me, or from someone else with the same email address as me? etc. TL;DR; email was designed before people really thought about security and bolting on even simple-sounding things ends up being a pain in the butt.